# Contact form made with React and PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a contact form on a website and I recently uploaded my code to a host/domain, but when I tried to submit on the form I was met with a screen that said *"Oops, looks like the page is lost."* I had run npm build beforehand and I don't see any contact.php file so maybe that's the issue (probably not)? I'm pretty lost because I've tried a lot of tutorials/fixes but they either weren't applicable to me or they were difficult to understand. I might need to use useStates (I've tried) but I would think it could still work without them.

Here's the jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import './contact.css';

const Contact = () => (
  <div className="contactContainer" id="contact">
    <div className="contentContainer" id="contact">
      <h1 className="contactMe">Contact Me</h1>
      <form className="formContainer" method="post" action="contact.php">
        <div className="input-group">
          <div className="nameContainer">
            <label className="nameLabel" htmlFor="name"> <input className="nameInput" type="text" id="nname" placeholder="Full Name" required /> </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="input-group">
          <label htmlFor="email"> <input className="emailInput" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required /> </label>
        </div>
        <div className="input-group">
          <label htmlFor="message"> <textarea className="messageTextArea" id="message" rows="8" placeholder="Your Message" /> </label>
        </div>
        <button className="submitButton" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Contact;
```

and here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $visitor_email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $email_from = "contact@dylancamacho.com";

    $email_subject = "New Portfolio Form Submission";

    $email_body = "Full Name: $name.\n".
                    "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                    "User Message: $message.\n";
    
    $to = "dcamacho@g.hmc.edu";

    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    header("Location: Contact.jsx")
?>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Comment: Can you provide the network when the call is made? it looks like is a relative path issue, after calling action="contact.php" you need to make sure the path is correct for example localhost/contact.php, if the URL is not correct that is why you get a 404 error

Comment: _"I don't see any contact.php file so maybe that's the issue (probably not)?"_ - If you're trying to access a non-existing URL (like the target file `contact.php` you san you can't find), then yeah, that can definitely be the reason why the server responds with a message that it can't find that file.

Comment: @CarlosGutierrez contact.php is located in the same folder as Contact.jsx. I've tried changing the code to `action="../contact.php"` and `header("Location: ../Contact.jsx")` but that also doesn't work. The error message on my local host is "Cannot POST /contact.php". On my website hosted with hostinger I get the 404 error.

Comment: @M.Eriksson the reason why I don't think this is the issue is that it doesn't make sense to me that the PHP just disappears when I run npm build. I figure it's just combined into one of the build files. I've tried adding back contact.php into the js folder of my build folder so that it's next to the js code but that hasn't worked. Regardless the issue persists on my local host where the build doesn't hide contact.php (although I've heard forms shouldn't work on local host).

Comment: I don't see what npm has to do with your PHP files, unless you have some custom rules in there that specifically targets PHP files? PHP and JS/CSS works totally different. In JS/CSS, you tend to build the application using multiple files, which you then you compile them into one JS and one CSS file you include. PHP doesn't work like that. In PHP, you build it using multiple files and then keep them like that. You don't build all your PHP into one single file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the URL, NPM can not run PHP files, you need Apache or Nginx. You need to create your React app inside one of those and then you are able to run PHP files basically the PHP file will run on localhost:8080 using Apache or Nginx and react on the usual localhost:3000. If you don't have a correct configuration to run PHP you will never be able to run the contact.php